# How to uninstall XGBoost from source (python)?

Tags: python, uninstallation, xgboost

A while back I installed the python version of XGBoost from source using these instructions (top of the thread): https://www.kaggle.com/c/liberty-mutual-group-property-inspection-prediction/discussion/15742

However, I need to update my version of XGBoost, which I assume means uninstalling the current version and doing a fresh install with the updated code. However I can't seem to be able to uninstall XGBoost. When I try `pip uninstall xgboost` I get `Cannot uninstall requirement xgboost, not installed`, when I try `conda uninstall xgboost` I get `Error: no packages found to remove from environment: /Users/XXXXX/anaconda2/envs/ml`. I've scoured the net and XGBoost github repo to try and track down some instructions but have not been able to.

Any idea?

Computer details: Mac osx 10.12 sierra, python 2.7

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just install the latest version the same way you installed the older version? If all things remain same (like the folder paths, variables) then there should not be any problem, and the newer version will replace the old.